# Ask patches in ellipse

Tags: netlogo

Can you create a method **"patches-in-ellipse"** with arguments (a,b, heading)? (similarly to "patches-in-radius")

Or can I query these patches someway (easily)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a function that can calculate an ellipse based on xy origin, the distance to the foci, the angle (in degrees from 0), and the max distance from the foci. I'm basing this off of the [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse) and the answer by Jim [on this thread](http://netlogo-users.18673.x6.nabble.com/Elliptical-shape-code-td5006231.html).

```
to setup
  ca
  reset-ticks
end

to ellipse [ x y d angle maxdist ] 

  ; origin x and y, distance to foci, angle in degrees, max distance from foci

  ask patches [set pcolor black]

  let f1x ( x + ( d * sin angle ) )
  let f1y ( y + ( d * cos angle ) )
  let f2x ( x - ( d * sin angle ) ) 
  let f2y ( y - ( d * cos angle ) )

  ask patches with [
    ( distancexy f1x f1y ) + ( distancexy f2x f2y ) <= maxdist ] [
    set pcolor red
  ]

  tick

end
```

To actually return the patch set contained by this ellipse, you could use this reporter:

```
to-report patches-in-ellipse [ x y d angle maxdist ] 

  let f1x ( x + ( d * sin angle ) )
  let f1y ( y + ( d * cos angle ) )
  let f2x ( x - ( d * sin angle ) ) 
  let f2y ( y - ( d * cos angle ) )

  report patches with [ ( distancexy f1x f1y ) + ( distancexy f2x f2y ) <= maxdist ] 

end
```

**EDIT:**

to calculate ellipse using a and b as shown [here](http://www.softschools.com/math/calculus/finding_the_foci_of_an_ellipse/), check out this program- copy and paste this into a new model and create a `setup` button and a forever `go` button to watch the turtle wander around with its ellipse:

```
to setup
  resize-world -50 50 -50 50
  set-patch-size 5
  ca
  crt 1 [
    set size 3
  ]
  reset-ticks
end


to go 
  ask patches [ set pcolor black ]
  ask turtles [ 
    rt random 30 - 15 
    fd 1
  ]
  draw-ellipse
  tick
end


to-report ellipse-a-b-heading [ x y a b head ]   
  let c sqrt ( ( (a) ^ 2 ) - ( (b) ^ 2 ) )

  let f1x ( x + ( c * sin head ) )
  let f1y ( y + ( c * cos head ) )
  let f2x ( x - ( c * sin head ) )
  let f2y ( y - ( c * cos head ) )

  ask patch f1x f1y [ set pcolor blue ]
  ask patch f2x f2y [ set pcolor blue ]
  print sqrt ( ( b ^ 2 ) + ( c ^ 2 ) )

  report patches with [ 
    ( distancexy f1x f1y ) + 
    ( distancexy f2x f2y ) <= 
    2 * ( sqrt ( ( b ^ 2 ) + ( c ^ 2 ) ) ) ]
end


to draw-ellipse
  let a 10
  let b 5

  ask turtles [
    ask ellipse-a-b-heading xcor ycor a b ( heading + 90 ) [
      set pcolor red
    ]
  ]
end
```

Note that the function `ellipse-a-b-heading` takes 5 inputs: an x, a y, the semi major axis, the semi minor axis, and the heading. However, the turtle provides almost all of those values, as shown in the `draw-ellipse` procedure. So, you just need to choose values for a and b however you like.

Is that closer to what you were after?

Comment: The angle means the heading of the turtle?
What is maxdist? Where are a and b?
I cant accept it in this way.

Comment: http://www.softschools.com/math/calculus/finding_the_foci_of_an_ellipse/

I can't accept it, sorry. That's not the answer to my question.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. It is helpful to include details like that in the body of your question, especially in cases where variables can have multiple meanings- a and b mean different things in regards to an ellipse depending on the source. So to further clarify: you want to return a patch-set of patches contained within an ellipse calculated using the current coordinates and heading of a turtle, and the *a* and *b* as shown in the [first figure in your link?](http://www.softschools.com/math/calculus/images/finding_the_foci_of_an_ellipse_img_2.png)

Comment: Yes, exactly :). a: semi-major; b: semi-minor axis. And the heading should overlap with the semi-minor axis (b). Like the body of a people.

Comment: @pnz Ok, based on your comment I have made an edit to my answer. See if that solution is closer to what you were looking for!